# SQL Server Convert Data

Tags: sql-server

I'm having trouble trying to clean a database because SQL Server doesn't differentiate '2¹59' from '2159', but when when try to convert into `INT` it obviously returns an error.

In this case I need to replace by `NULL`, every non numerical data.

Can someone help please? (I'm using Sql Server 2008)

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using it..is it sql 2012 or higher..If yes then there are few new function that can reduce efforts.

Answer (score 1):

From SQL SERVER 2012 there is a new function which have been added called TRY_PARSE,
If you use it then it will automatically make non int to null.

```
select TRY_PARSE('2¹59' as int)
```

Output of above query will be null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different collation to change the way the strings are compared:

```
select
  case when N'2¹59' = N'2159' collate Latin1_General_BIN then 1 else 0 end
```

This will select `0` as you'd expect.

More importantly, since MS SQL understands unicode properly, you can do this:

```
select cast(N'2¹59' as varchar)
```

which will give you `'2159'` - properly replacing the "broken" digits.

If you have no other option, you could also build a helper table to handle indexing the string (just a single column with numbers 1..1000 for example), and do something like this:

```
exists 
 (
  select 1 from [Numbers] 
  where 
   [Numbers].[Index] < len([Value]) + 1
    and 
   unicode(substring([Value], [Numbers].[Index], 1)) > 127
 )
```

Needless to say, this is going to be rather slow. For simple integers, though, this can work as a decent validation - simply use `(unicode(substring([Value], [Numbers].[Index], 1)) not between 48 and 57) and ([Numbers].[Index] <> 0 or substring([Value], 1, 1) <> '-'))` for example.

Comment: Firts, thank you for your help. I´m using SQL Server 2008. So, I've tried to use your third option but it returned one for every row (even the row the containing '2¹59', I've probably done something wrong).  The problem with the first option is that I don´t know how to compare this for every row in my table, even why I only use an example, there are other problems like this (¹,²,³...) in different rows.  And the second one, actually gave me 2¹59' instead of '2159'. Plus, I have to ignore that line, I can't assume that this ¹ is equivalent to 1.

Comment: @Camila Are you sure you're using `nvarchar` columns and variables? The `N` is critical for a literal, otherwise you're constructing a `varchar` literal rather than `nvarchar`.